# Носители английского языка понимают C++ глубже или хуже?

Tags: c++

Как это, когда видишь к примеру while и не воспринимаешь его как какую-то абстракцию, а видишь слово пока/до тех пор пока? А в C++ почти все можно перевести, то есть это бы выглядело для нас примерно так : [image]

Понятно, что первое время будет плохая читаемость, но а в будущем это способствует лучшему понимаю или вредит?

Comment: Когда я читаю код 1С, у меня нет батхерта, значит аналогично.  
Но тут скорее всего все очень индивидуально по первому времени, а когда вырабатывается привычка, то не имеет значения знаешь ты этот язык или нет.  
Англичане же как-то пишут программы.

Comment: проблема существует только до тех пор, пока пытаетесь прочитать слово и перевести его, осмыслить. Со временем слова воспринимаются как отдельные сущности, как нечто единое и проблемы понимания нет. Думаю, даже если бы вместо слов были кружочки, квадратики, стрелочки, то порог вхождения конечно был немножко выше, но потом никаких проблем.

Не нужно считать, что язык программирования связан с языком общения. Это два совершенно разных, хоть и похожих немного с виду, языка.

Comment: Вряд ли `cin` или `cout` ассоциируются буквально с "ввести" и "вывести" у англоговорящих.

Comment: если верить автору, то cin читается как `see in`, то есть "смотри ввод". cout - как `see out` - смотри вывод. То есть, вполне себе читабельно.

Comment: Английский язык сейчас lingua franca программирования. Если программист не знает английского, у него горааааздо бОльшие проблемы.

Comment: а я бы не хотел программировать на русском.. Потому что сейчас я сразу вижу, где у меня код, а где текст для вывода (я имею ввиду php)

Comment: @KoVadim, вот этот ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262232/what-does-the-c-mean-in-cout-cin-cerr-and-clog говорит от том, что предположение не верно. Страуструп имел в виду слово character. Другая более популярная версия это, что "c" в cout и cin означает console, что вполне логично. И out и in тоже являются сокращениями от output и input - ввод и вывод. Таким образом получается, что cout это character output по версии Страуструпа и console output (по общеизвестной версии).

Comment: @KoVadim вообще языки высокого уровня для того и придумали чтобы в абстракции натурального языка завернуть конкреции машинного. Я считаю что нативное или глубокое понимание английского, конечно приносит плюсов в понимание структуры языков и фреймворков. Т.е. понять почему сущность называется pointer гораздо проще для англоязычного и пренебрегать семантикой английского(или нативного для архитектора языка/приложения/фреймворка) ни в именовании конструкций ни в именовании сущностей ни в коем случае нельзя. иначе унас получится очередной ассемблер.

Comment: (не надо говорить только про объекты, проц тоже можно научить объектами ворочать).

Comment: @strol в вашем примере "число" как-то слабо определено, надо или "целое" писать или "натуральное" или ещё как-то а-то в ряд чисел входят и комплексные. Вообще, мне кажется, что русский язык плохо приспособлен для программирования, слишком сложен что-ли, порядок частей предложения не закреплен к примеру, значение слов в большей степени зависит от контекста итд. 1С'ик меня пугает, если честно.

Comment: eicto, русский для стихов хорош и прочего литературного творчества.  А для изучения к примеру английского, имхо очень плох, так как вы говорите из-за сложности и к примеру не закрепленности частей предложение, получаются иногда ощутимые барьеры с переводом предложений на английский, потому как правила можно выучить, но менять с их помощью быстро на ходу все речевые обороты в предложениях - провал. Я уже молчу о большом количестве переводов одного слова или фразы. Явная не стыковка языков. И ещё очень много трудностей. Хотя американцу выучить русский на уровне носителя - ещё больший провал.

Comment: Вообще-то давным-давно был создан язык, одной из целей которого была близость к естественному (в определённой степени) языку, чтобы непрограммисты могли читать программы. Последний всплеск активности на этом языке был в конце 90х (зарплаты вроде до $5000 в месяц. И это в прошлом веке!)

Comment: > А для изучения к примеру английского,

извините, а это как использовать русский для изучения английского ? В смысле native русский по вашему имеет какие-то сложности с этим и наоборот ? По поводу стишков и лит творчества... оно конечно да, но и обмен строгими данными между двумя носителями тоже возможен и он часто плотнее чем между англоговорящими.

Comment: Да, я имел ввиду, что носителю русского может быть сложно выучить английским, потому как первая же проблема - это наличие множества слов с похожим смыслом, которые на английском описываются одним словом и придется искать уйму контекстов, чтобы закрепить уместность употребления тех или иных слов. Это не считая новых слов из-за суффиксов, префиксов и прочих шалостей. Ну а дальше проблемы с родом и окончанием и ещё пара сотней, для которых не хватит  тут комментариев. В общем было бы прекрасно сделать 1 язык в мире, который был бы максимально подходящим для всех.

Comment: @strol Так был уже. Вавилонский.

Comment: Так нечего было башни строить).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Думаю кое-какая фора у англоговорящих есть. Но это зависит явно не от того, что языковые конструкции записаны английскими словами. Как известно, языки программирования очень сильно отличаются от естественных языков - обычные языки более запутанны, имеют больший словарный состав, подчиняются куда более странным и нелепым правилам с тысячей исключений, фразы в них могут содержать два и более смысловых значения (а иногда и вовсе ни одного). Разумеется, многое из этого в языках программирования немыслимо. А потому программный код никогда не воспринимается как обычный повествовательный текст. Конечно, человеку, не знакомому с программированием, какие-то элементарные вещи могут показаться более понятными, если он будет знать, что if - это "если", а new - это "новый". Но это весьма поверхностное восприятие, все ассоциации с конкретными словами из человеческих языков стираются очень быстро, и спустя какое-то время new из C++ для программиста уже не имеет ни малейшей связи с английским словом. Стоит также отметить, что языки программирования даже в своих элементарных конструкциях состоят далеко не только из слов, но и из тьмы различных симвовов вроде { }, &, *, ^, ?: и тд, что также снижает похожесть кода на человеческий язык.

Как я говорил выше, полагаю, что определенное преимущество у англоязычных программистов на начальном этапе имеется. Но оно кроется в куда более прозаичных вещах - на английском написано большинство фундаментальных трудов по программированию, практически вся документация к языкам, множество справочной информации, и лишь некоторая часть всего этого разнообразия переведена на другие языки. С другой стороны, это преимущество не настолько огромно, чтобы относитться к нему серьезно - те, кто не может/не хочет изучить английский на должном (к счастью, не особо высоком) уровне, просто отсеиваются, а оставшиеся впоследствии вполне успешно могут пользоваться теми или иными материалами на языке Дж. Буша и Б. Питта

Answer (score 4):

Вот это "Hello world" на Fjölnir (разработан в Исландии):

```
"hello" < main
{
   main ->
   stef(;)
   stofn
       skrifastreng(;"Halló, heimur!"),
   stofnlok
}
*
"GRUNNUR"
;
```

Я знаю английский, но не знаю исландского, поэтому я ничего не понял (можно лишь догадываться).
А вот это Hello world на Java c применением библиотеки Swing:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;  
public class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();           
                frame.setTitle("Hi!");                 
                frame.add(new JLabel("Hello, world!"));
                frame.pack();                          
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);     
                frame.setVisible(true);                
        }
}
```

Я не знаю Java (абсолютно), но знаю английский, поэтому я понял, что делает конкретно каждая строчка этого кода даже без комментариев, хотя пример кода на Java сложнее первого.
Естественно, я потрачу гораздо меньше времени на глубокое изучение Java. Если бы мне пришлось изучать Fjölnir, я бы для начала занялся изучением исландского.

Comment: Бывают конфузы и при чтении программ на "англоязычных" языках программирования, когда автор называет переменные и процедуры, и пишет комментарии на своем родном языке, например испанском (или на том же исландском) :)

Comment: ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/AAMAxr8.png

Comment: Автору этого кода нужно поменять редактор. Если бы открывающая квадратная скобка не была жирной, можно было бы принять ее за букву С.

Comment: наверное уже были прецеденты, раз все-таки выделенные). Представляю какие кошмары будут ночью снится, после прочтения 1к строчек кода.

Comment: @Lucky, тогда уж не редактор, а знакогенератор.

Если кому интересно, Гугль мне тут подсказывает, что это [Агат](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82_%28%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%29), а язык - [РАПИРА](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).